# Toggle nested comments

Tags: comments, jquery, threading

I am trying to find a solution to toggle (hide/show) threaded comments. I need to see only comments 1,2,3 etc... and hide 1.1,1.2,1.3 etc...
Clicking "show comments" will toggle and display the thread of comments.

example:

1 ---

-----clicking "show more comments" shows

----- 1.1

----- 1.2

----- 1.3

----- ...

2 ---

-----clicking "show more comments" shows

----- 2.1

----- 2.2

----- 2.3

----- ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/K3gr7/4/

I used an ordered list to markup the comments. You probably need to tweak it to your own setup, and cache some variables for optimization, but the functionality is in there.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Toggle all
    $('#toggle-all').click(function() {
        var $subcomments = $('#comments').find('> li > ol');
        if ($subcomments.filter(':hidden').length) {
            $subcomments.slideDown();
        } else {
            $subcomments.slideUp();
        }
    });

    // Add buttons to threaded comments
    $('#comments').find('> li > ol')
        .before('<button class="toggle">Show more comments</button>');

   // Toggle one section
    $('#comments').find('button.toggle').click(function() {
        $(this).next('ol').slideToggle();
    }); 
});
```

I misread your question at first, that's why I added a "toggle all" button and left it in there as a free bonus.

Comment: Tweaked and working! Thanks, that was easy and I learned some new jQuery stuff! Thanks!!

Comment: I tried the above code, but noticed that instead of having 'ol' I have 'ul' on the child comments. It seems the standard wp output is 'ol-li--ul-li---li' Would you mind posting a moded vs. of the little script to work with children comments that use 'ul' instead of 'ol'?

Comment: @shawn: http://jsfiddle.net/K3gr7/12/